# C program to count symbols in a file (without \n \t ' ') and print the line with the most of the symbols and the line with the least amount of symbols

Tags: c

So I have this big assigment for university  and I am a beginner in programming and I need little bit of help with this program I am writing.So basically I have to write a program which counts the symbols and characters on every line in a file(without '\n', '\t', ' ') and to print out the line with the most symbols and characters and that one with the least.
For example if I have in the file
1.Hello my name is Martin
2.I love meatballs
3.Bacon is great

It should print out for example:

"Line number 1 has the most characters and line number 3 has the least characters".

```
for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
{
   if(c=='\n')
   {
      lines++;
   }
   if (c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c!= ' ')
   {
      count++;
   }
}
```

I made the symbol count and the line count but everything else is darkness.Please help thank you.

Comment: You are counting symbols through total file in `count`. How could you count only the symbols in the current line? Where to store that count. How to find out whether the current count is smaller than the smallest previous or larger than the largest previous? Note that for some of the counts, you will want to "forget" them and restart from 0.

Comment: By the way, you might find the cool stuff presented in the [tour] interesting and helpful for your future participation on StackOverflow.

Comment: I tried to store both the line number and symbol count in arrays but I just couldn't make connection between the two arrays..

Comment: And one more question how to make that "forget" wdy mean :D

Comment: Read the five words in my comment which follow the "forget". Please understand that I do no actually intend to give you a solution. The questions I asked are to make you think along the right way and thereby make you help yourself. And (I think) the questions as I asked them do read like pseudo code to experienced programmers, maybe with a touch of line-shuffling. So, please read your text book and look for anything that sounds similar to my questions. Arrays however seem unnecessary. A simpler solution is hinted at in my questions.

Answer (score 1):

** Edit ** My apologies, thanks for pointing out the inadequacies.

From what the assignment description sounds like, you don't need to count the total number of symbols in the entire text file, but the total number of symbols per line. Have a few variables for line number with least symbols, the least amount of symbols, the line number with the most symbols, and the largest amount of symbols. Each time as you read a line, have a temporary variable that counts the non-whitespace symbols as long as the character is not '\n'. Once you reach '\n', check if 1) the current line count is either smaller than the smallest count or 2) the current line count is larger than the largest count. If so, update the new counts and the new line numbers.

I'd code it as this:

```
int lineNO = 1;
int leastLine, mostLine, currCount, leastCount, mostCount = 0;
int c;

while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
   if (c == '\n') {
      /* check if currCount < leastCount or if currCount > mostCount */
      /* if so, update the necessary lineNO's */
      currCount = 0;
      lineNO++;
   }

   if (c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c!= ' ') {
      currCount++;
   }   
}
```

Comment: `ispsace()` is also true for characters  other than `'\n'`, `'\t'`, `' '`.

Comment: Your proposals (while not totally unreasonable) are a matter of coding style (yours is admittedly prettier). This would make a decent comment, but is nowhere near answering OPs question. Changing the code parts which actually already work as desired will hardly be considered helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your help.I was able to write the program and find the leastLine - here is the code:

```
         int lineNO = 1;
         int  mostLine, currCount, leastCount[200], mostCount = 0;
          int c;
         int len=0;
           int leastLine[200];
              while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
          if (c == '\n') {
           currCount = 0;
            lineNO++;
              leastLine[lineNO]=lineNO;
          }

          if (c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c!= ' ') {
           currCount++;
             leastCount[lineNO]=currCount;
          }

       }
         int i;
       for(i=0;i<=lineNO;i++){
    if(leastCount[0]>leastCount[i]){
        leastCount[0]=leastCount[i];
        leastLine[0]=leastLine[i];
    }
     }



        printf("%d",leastLine[0]);
```

But there are some problems:

1.If I change this line and instead of leastCound[0]>leastCount[i] I change greater than to less than I getsomething like "-327806".

2.In my "text.txt" file(the file where I test my program) if line 1 is the leastLine , the program doesn't count it as the leastLine..

I get this when I modify the program to print all numbers and lines :https://pasteboard.co/GY2wLq7.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the arrays to keep track of the line numbers and their lengths and then iterating over the arrays to check which line number has the least characters, I think it would be easier to just keep track of the counts with the variables that I used above: `leastLine, mostLine, currCount, leastCount, mostCount`.

What I would do in the commented area is:

```
if (currCount < leastCount) {
   leastCount = currCount;
   leastLine = lineNO;
}

else if (currCount > mostCount) {
   mostCount = currCount;
   mostLine = lineNO;
}
```

You would also need to do this check at the end, after the while loop, because you wouldn't be able to check the last line otherwise. (Unless you slightly modify the while loop.)

If you really want to use an array to keep track of the lengths, I'd suggest an array declared like this: `int lineLengths[200]`, where the index (1 - 199, not 0-199 because line numbers start at 1 so in order to avoid confusion, it would be easier to leave the first element at index 0 empty) represents the line number, and the value at the index would be the number of characters. Then, you could iterate over this array to find the smallest and largest counts and store the line numbers for both.